# What is the architecture of a social networking program?

Tags: architecture, social-networking, software-design

For instance, when Mark Zuckerberg says in an interview that he wrote Facebook in 2 weeks, what exactly (or at least approximately) did he write? I imagine "user" objects in a big database or tree with the ability to negotiate links to other user objects, but I'm wondering how the overarching manager of the tree works. When a user log in, does the "main" program look up that user's object and fork off a process with it to interact with other user object while the user is logged in? Thanks.

Comment: a user table, a pictures table, and a userInPictures table... is there more behind it?

Comment: It's not rocket science, that's for sure.  It was a relatively simple web app that has grown over time.  In two weeks he probably wrote a registration and login system, with a basic 'wall' and image support.

Comment: Actually, Zuckerberg wrote *TheFacebook* in 2 weeks, not Facebook.  Facebook took a little longer.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're kindof dancing around a topic that I don't feel you understand. To understand how he wrote Facebook, you need to know:

- How to write a web page (HTML, CSS, & JavaScript)
- A server-side language (PHP, in the case of Facebook)
- How to use an RDBMS system (MySQL is a popular one)

Learn those three topics, and it will come into focus.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the scope of the application, "social app" is too generic a definition to specify an architecture in detail. User relations is just a part of such a system: messaging, groups, ratings, etc. you have to define the participation aspect, the social graph and presence. You usually build an app focusing on a strategy rather than the implementation details.